# Making sure to always run the dnvm and dnu commands by adding to .bash_profile

Tags: .net, ubuntu, mono, dnvm, dnu

I was following along [Installing ASP.NET 5 and DNX](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/runtimes/ASPnet5#_installing-aspnet-5-and-dnx) post and here I'm stuck:

> **Tip**: Add the following to your `.bash_profile` and restart the Terminal. The first line will ensure that you can always run the `dnvm` and `dnu` commands. The second line works around a known bug in Mono where you may see the IOException `FileSystemWatcher has reached the maximum number of files to watch` when running your application.

```
source dnvm.sh
export MONO_MANAGED_WATCHER=disabled
```

My simple question is:

- How to add it to `.bash_profile`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.bash_profile` is a file that sits at `~/`. You should be able to open it with a text editor and add those commands.

Alternatively you can do this in your terminal.

```
echo 'source dnvm.sh' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export MONO_MANAGED_WATCHER=disabled' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Whats happening here is you are appending a piece of text `'source dnvm.sh'` into a specific file.

The `echo` command prints the text, and the `>>` shift operator appends the text to the file which is `.bash_profile` located at `~/`.

Comment: Glad I could help :)